# Request URL in Django error message does not correspond to the acual request url

Tags: django, nginx, http-status-code-500, daphne

I'm building an app with Django and Django-Rest-Framework. The frontend js application makes API calls to the backend. It works well when I test it using `python manage.py ruserver` but when i test it in a VM similar to my production environment, all API request get a 500 response.

In the error message, the Request URL does not correspond to the actual request that was made.

The actual request url looks like this:

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/account/login/

But the error message says it is something like this:

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/path/to/my/djoserapp/on/server/api/account/login/

The server is configured with nginx and daphne and the django version is 3.1

Here is my Nginx config :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/app;
    }
    location /media/ {
       root /home/app;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/app.sock;
    }
}
```

I don't know where to begin solving this and will greatly appreciate any help i could get.

Thank you

Comment: please paste your `nginx` config here.

Comment: Thanks @ahmadgh74 , it is done.

Comment: please update your question with the content of the file `proxy_params`